# Google Plus Vanity URL Dilema

Tags: seo, google, facebook, google-plus

Google Plus has just made vanity URLs available for pages, wanted your advice.

The page is pre approved (so all I need to is click accept) to get

```
www.google.com/+shoes
```

But my FB vanity URL is

```
www.facebook.com/shoestorename
```

Should I take the highly valuable name (in my opinion) or should I take the less valuable but match it with my FB page?

```
www.google.com/+showstorename
```

*Note: The page is not about Shoes but just as valuable*

I would appreciate as many people's point of view on this.

Comment: IMHO typical example of (un)social networks creating new nonsense necessities. My POV, is why do you mind this? Moreover https://www.facebook.com/shoestorename is a 404

Comment: @MarcoDemaio I do agree. It is far more inflated than it should be, however who am I to judge, Google may do what Google wants we just make the best of it :)

Comment: Why don't you accept it, in the worst case later on you can always create a 2nd (useless) G+ profile called www.google.com/+showstorename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When social media is 'done right', branding should be consistent across all channels so if the vanity URL you possess at Facebook is correct and you plan to continue using this, then your Google+ vanity URL should be consistent with this. Furthermore, you should be looking to secure the same vanity URL's for all social media profiles for your brand.

Google is the one network that isn't going to let broad and generic based keywords in vanity URL's overshadow legitimate and branded pages.